# Most concise way to extract file name extension

Tags: string, d

Which would be the most concise way to extract the extension from a filename string (including and not including the last dot `.`) in the D language? Right now I'm using `lastIndexOf()`. Is there a cleaner/preferable way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`std.path.extension`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_path.html#.extension). e.g.

```
assert("file.foo".extension == ".foo");
```